# How do i recongize artifacts and holes using OpenCV in a image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I need help with OpenCV
I have a picture with a complex for lying on the ground now i need to extract this form from the picture and cleaned it from noise. But now there is a logo which i need to remove and 4 holes to identify.[What i could do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYuC5.png) [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ksSm.jpg)

My code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Read the original image
img = cv2.imread('Amoebe_1.jpg') 
# resize image
scale_down = 0.4
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx= scale_down, fy= scale_down, interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Display original image
cv2.imshow('Original', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Denoising
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,20,10,10,21)

# Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(image=dst, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) # Canny Edge Detection

# Contour Detection
contours1, hierarchy1 = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contours on the original image for `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`
image_copy1 = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_copy1, contours1, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
# see the results
cv2.imshow('Simple approximation', image_copy1)

# Display Canny Edge Detection Image
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Floodfill
h,w,chn = img.shape
seed = (w/2,h/2)
mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2),np.uint8)
bucket = edges.copy()
cv2.floodFill(bucket, mask, (0,0), (255,255,255))
cv2.imshow('Mask', bucket)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why the resizing in the beginning ? How much do you care about runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Having a shot at this in ImageJ, extracting the red channel from the raw image gives me this:

[image: red channel]

Which is close to a binary image already. Running a small (3pix) median filter and thresholding gives this as a binary:

[image: binary]

Running `cv.findContours()` on that last one and analysing contour areas should give you the little holes and the "eye". Use `cv.drawContours()` with the bigger objects to fill up the eye and logo area, maybe `dilate()` to fill small discrepancies.